# Android webview goes through action when setTranslucentStatus is true

Tags: android, layout, webview, android-actionbar

This is my second time building an Android app, but it is my first time I want to use "Material Design".

The problem is that the webview goes trough the action when the systembar / status bar has a translucent tint.

So the questionis...how can I prevent the webview from rendering/showing trough the action bar?

If you need more information of my setup, be free to ask!

Thanks for the help!

I can't post images yet :/ because of my reputation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In styles.xml add this:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/color_primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/color_primary_dark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent_color</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
</style>
```

and in colors.xml define your custom colors like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="color_primary">#009933</color>
    <color name="color_primary_dark">#009933</color>
    <color name="accent_color">#009933</color>
</resources>
```

then in manifest define your style in application tag like:

```
<application
 ...
 ....
   android:theme="@style/MyTheme" >
```

Comment: I tried, but it seems not to work unfortunately, is there any other possibility?

Comment: I wish I could, but I need to spend more time on this website to be able to give you some credit you deserve :(